# Automatic Barcode Capture in Windows Phone 7 using Zxing?

Tags: windows-phone-7

as of now i am starting the camara and captures the image if it contains barcode then decode it and displaying the Barcode text.
But i want when the camera starts it is enable until barcode is found if whenever found the barcode then decode it and display the text.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx) may be helpful for you. Author proposes the wrapper for `zxing` library

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following blog post useful :-

http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston